# Select Insert Statement returns 1000 fields instead of 10

Tags: sql, sql-server

currently, I have this code in sql server that is supposed to get values from a database and put them into another database.

```
Insert into AppleFinalX.[dbo].SalesFactTable(SalesType, TotalSales, SalesHDRDate, ProductSales, ProductID) 
SELECT AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.SalesType,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.TotalSales,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.SalesHDRDate,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesDetailsTable.PurchaseAmount,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].ProductTable.ProductID
FROM AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable, 
     AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesDetailsTable, 
     AppleFinal.[dbo].ProductTable
```

Basically, it gets values from three tables from a different database (AppleFinal), and puts them in a table in a different database (AppleFinalX). But unfortunately, it returns 1000 records instead of 10. Anyone know why this is happening? :( All tables have 10 records each so I was shocked to see 1000 records in the new table...

Comment: You're using a cartesian join by selecting from multiple tables with no condition.

Comment: You need JOIN conditions!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: That is because you are missing a JOIN condition on the three tables.

Comment: This is not a good practice of writing statement, it will be very costly in tables with millions of rows, neways did u researched for using `distinct`

Comment: Mathematically speaking, a CARTESIAN JOIN joins all columns in all combinations. So the total row count expected is product of all rows in each table. So, 10 rows in each table is 10 * 10 * 10 = 1,000. You are getting the correct result, even though its not what you are expecting. Be very careful with CARTESIAN JOINS, you can easily explode the row count processed. You need join conditions.

Comment: @Ven, distinct is not the solution here - the problem is missing join conditions. (And distinct can be very expensive too.)

Comment: @jarlh i agree distinct can be very expensive too, I guess OP considers with every one's comments on how to use joins and best practices, a million row insert can be tripled aswel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, you are joining each row of each table to each row of every other table.  That's obviously not what you wanted.  Using the JOIN command is the solution.  Something like this:

```
SELECT AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.SalesType,
   AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.TotalSales,
   AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.SalesHDRDate,
   AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesDetailsTable.PurchaseAmount,
   AppleFinal.[dbo].ProductTable.ProductID
FROM AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable
    INNER JOIN AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesDetailsTable
        ON  AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.ID = AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesDetailsTable.SalesID
    INNER JOIN AppleFinal.[dbo].ProductTable
        ON AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesDetailsTable.ProductID = AppleFinal.[dbo].ProductTable.ID
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and tweaked it a bit and it worked, thank u very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Far better to explicitly state your joins :

```
INSERT INTO AppleFinalX.dbo.SalesFactTable
            (SalesType, TotalSales, SalesHDRDate, ProductSales, ProductID) 

SELECT sh.SalesType,
       sh.TotalSales,
       sh.SalesHDRDate,
       sd.PurchaseAmount,
       pt.ProductID

FROM AppleFinal.dbo.SalesHDRTable  sh
    LEFT JOIN   AppleFinal.dbo.SalesDetailsTable sd ON  sd.saleType = sh.saleType
    LEFT JOIN   AppleFinal.dbo.ProductTable pt      ON pt.ProductID = sh.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I would prefer to apply necessary join but also try this:

```
Insert into AppleFinalX.[dbo].SalesFactTable(SalesType, TotalSales, SalesHDRDate, ProductSales, ProductID) 
SELECT AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.SalesType,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.TotalSales,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.SalesHDRDate,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesDetailsTable.PurchaseAmount,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].ProductTable.ProductID
FROM AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable, 
     AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesDetailsTable, 
     AppleFinal.[dbo].ProductTable
group by AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.SalesType,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.TotalSales,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesHDRTable.SalesHDRDate,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].SalesDetailsTable.PurchaseAmount,
       AppleFinal.[dbo].ProductTable.ProductID
```